# Bitbucket, show diff in PR respect to another branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

There exists the possibility, using BitBucket, to show the diff in a pull request not respect to the branch where the pull request goes but respect to another branch?

My scenario is: I have two open pull request, one based on the other. For a better code review, I want to show, in the second review, only the change between the first and the second but, the final result has to be merge in master, graphically:

```
|
|
|
x master
 \
  \
   \ 
    \
PR1 - x featureBranch1
      |
       \ 
        \
         \
PR2 ----- x featureBranch2
```

The idea is that pull request of featureBranch2 shows only the diff between featureBranch1 and featureBranch2. Something similar, I've seen, exists with ReviewBoard tool that permits to set a specific `--parent` to compute the diff instead of using the final branch.

Comment: Create a pull-request with SOURCE=featureBranch2 and TARGET=featureBranch1.  You can choose any TARGET branch you like for a pull-request, it doesn't have to be master.

Comment: What happens to the FeatureBranch2 PR if FeatureBranch1 PR is merged before?